# Using Python Parse to get a string of numbers, letters, whitespace, and symbols

Tags: python, string, parsing

I am attempting to parse a log using the Parse library from Python. (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parse) For my purposes I need to use the type specifiers in the format string, however, some of the data that I am parsing might be a combination of several of those types.

For example:

```
"4.56|test-1 Cool|dog"
```

I can parse the number of the front using the format specifier g (general number) and w (word) for "dog" at the end. However, the middle phrase "test-1 Cool" is a number, letters, whitespace, and a dash. Using any of the specifiers alone doesn't seem to work (have tried W,w,s, and S). I would like to extract that phrase as a string.

Without the problem phrase, I would just do this:

```
test = "|4.56|dog|"
result = parse('|{number:g}|{word:w}|', test)
```

EDIT: I have had some success using a custom type conversion shown below:

```
def SString(string):
    return string

test = "|4.56|test-1 Cool|dog|"
result = parse('|{number:g}|{other:SString}|{word:w}|', test, dict(SString=SString))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with some code like this:

```
from parse import *

test = "4.56|test-1 Cool|dog"
result = parse('{number:g}|{other}|{word:w}', test)
print result
#<Result () {'other': 'test-1 Cool', 'word': 'dog', 'number': 4.56}>
```

Also, for type checking you can use `re` module (for example):

```
from parse import *
import re

def SString(string):
    if re.match('\w+-\d+ \w+',string):
        return string
    else:
        return None

test = "|4.56|test-1 Cool|dog|"
result = parse('|{number:g}|{other:SString}|{word:w}|', test, dict(SString=SString))
print(result)
#<Result () {'other': 'test-1 Cool', 'word': 'dog', 'number': 4.56}>

test = "|4.56|t3est Cool|dog|"
result = parse('|{number:g}|{other:SString}|{word:w}|', test, dict(SString=SString))
print(result)
#<Result () {'other': None, 'word': 'dog', 'number': 4.56}>
```

Comment: This would be great, but I really need the type specifier to be able to tell the type the user wanted as the parse string is inputted by a user. I am currently using a custom type conversion and it seems to be work ok, I will add it to my original post

Comment: @SethDavis check my answer now

Comment: Thanks! Although, it looks like the re.match line expects that specific format   when in reality it could be several different formats that do or do not contain whitespace, or numbers. "test 1-cool" "cool1 -test" "cool-test" should all work the same, returning just that as a string. I simply want the entire thing as a string, with a type specifier that tells me to expect a string. I believe the custom type conversion works great for this, but it is great to be introduced to the re library

Answer (score 1):

How about trying

```
test.split("|")
```

Comment: The string for parse is more convenient as it's easy to have in a config file and edit, also the type specifiers are useful as the data will be sent to a database which means I need to know what type each piece should be so that the datatype and the type of the column match